# How to reuse filesystem subtree amongst multiple jails?

Tags: freebsd, zfs, jail

I have a FreeBSD 11 host, and I want to setup multiple jails in it.
Official guide [suggests](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/jails-build.html) hard copying `/usr/bin` into each of the containers. Having that my jails shall be nearly identical, this seems wasteful for me.

It would be nice if I could reuse the same part of filesystem inside all of the jails, in the same manner as with Linux's `mount --bind -o ro <host /usr/bin> <jailed /usr/bin>`. It it possible?

Comment: The filesystem you are looking for is `nullfs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FreeBSD your can use [nullfs](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=nullfs&sektion=5&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.3-RELEASE%20and%20Ports) to mount subtree of filesystem.

There are several tools to make jail creating/updating more easy (listed in the [Freebsd Wiki](https://wiki.freebsd.org/Jails)). One of them [ezjail](http://erdgeist.org/arts/software/ezjail/) and ezjail uses nullfs to mount one basejail inside several jails.